# identicalCRS(x, y) is not TRUE error in R for individual tree detection using chm

Tags: r, raster, lidar

I have a LiDAR point cloud data for a dimension of 250*250 m^2 area (a forest region). I need to separate out individual trees using that data.

I created Canopy Height Model(CHM) using LASTools and used that CHM for tree delineation. I'm attaching that [chm file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5tmoxgs465398os/dem_test.tif?dl=0) (this raster will give the height information)

I tried to use `rLiDAR` package available in R.

I coded like this

```
library(rLiDAR)
schm <- CHMsmoothing(chm, "mean", 5)

# Setting the fws:
fws <- 5 # dimention 5x5

# Setting the specified height above ground for detectionbreak
minht <- 8.0

# Getting the individual tree detection list 
treeList <- FindTreesCHM(schm, fws, minht)
```

But it's giving an error

> Error: identicalCRS(x, y) is not TRUE

How can I overcome this?

Comment: How do you create `chm`? `chm <- raster()`?

Comment: Using lasheight, I created normalized height plot. I just need the max height from that data, so with that normalized height, I created dem(using las2dem) then I saved it as a tif file and loaded to R

Comment: It is not my question! How do you read your file in R?

Comment: chm <- raster('dem_test.tif')

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/wiki/Segment-individual-trees-and-compute-metrics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function `FindTreesCHM`, at lines 17-18, we find:

```
XYmax <- SpatialPoints(xyFromCell(setNull, Which(setNull == 
    1, cells = TRUE)))
```

Which creates a `SpatialPoints`. The problem is that object has no projection set:

```
projection(XYmax)
# [1] NA
```

Then, the line 19

```
htExtract <- over(XYmax, as(chm, "SpatialGridDataFrame"))
```

Throws an error because `XYmax` has no projection set, while `chm` has:

```
projection(chm)
# [1] "+proj=utm +zone=11 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

And as function `over` first check the projections of objects, we get the error:

```
identicalCRS(XYmax, as(chm, "SpatialGridDataFrame"))
# [1] FALSE
```

A workaround would be to write your own function, adding a line setting the projection of `XYmax` to the projection of `chm`.

Also, there is an error thrown by the line 22 because of line 21.

This function can be easily fixed, but I would highly recommend to contact the maintainer of the package (`maintainer("rLiDAR")`).

---

Here is one possible fix:

```
library(rLiDAR)
library(raster)

FindTreesCHM.fix <- function(chm, fws = 5, minht = 1.37) 
{
    if (class(chm)[1] != "RasterLayer") {
        chm <- raster(chm)
    }
    if (class(fws) != "numeric") {
        stop("The fws parameter is invalid. It is not a numeric input")
    }
    if (class(minht) != "numeric") {
        stop("The minht parameter is invalid. It is not a numeric input")
    }
    w <- matrix(c(rep(1, fws * fws)), nrow = fws, ncol = fws)
    chm[chm < minht] <- NA
    f <- function(chm) max(chm)
    rlocalmax <- focal(chm, fun = f, w = w, pad = TRUE, padValue = NA)
    setNull <- chm == rlocalmax
    XYmax <- SpatialPoints(xyFromCell(setNull, Which(setNull == 
        1, cells = TRUE)))
    projection(XYmax) <- projection(chm)
    htExtract <- over(XYmax, as(chm, "SpatialGridDataFrame"))
    treeList <- cbind(slot(XYmax, "coords"), htExtract)
    colnames(treeList) <- c("x", "y", "height")
    return(treeList)
}


chm <- raster("dem_test.tif")
schm <- CHMsmoothing(chm, "mean", 5)
fws <- 5
minht <- 8.0
treeList <- FindTreesCHM.fix(schm, fws, minht)

#           x       y  height
# 1  256886.5 4110940 14.1200
# 2  256805.5 4110884 13.8384
# 3  256756.5 4110880 15.2004
# 4  256735.5 4110874 17.6100
# 5  256747.5 4110840 18.2592
# 6  256755.5 4110828 19.9252
# 7  256777.5 4110806 12.7180
# 8  256780.5 4110802 14.6512
# 9  256780.5 4110792 15.8532
# 10 256763.5 4110786 18.7128
# 11 256766.5 4110764 14.4972
```

[image]

Comment: `edit(FindTreesCHM)`. I also edited the answer with a possible fix.

Comment: @bibinwilson  Please check the validity of the output.

Comment: by reducing the minht, I'm getting almost all trees. For the current research, I think it's enough.